# Explanation in Tosfos Pesachim Daf 99b

Tags: motzi-yedei-chovato, tosfot, four-cups-wine, maseches-pesachim

Tosfos writes the following in Pesachim Daf 99b:

> **לא יפחתו לו מארבע כוסות.** מתוך הלשון משמע קצת שאין נותנין לבניו ולבני ביתו כי אם לעצמו והוא מוציא את כולם בשלו וסברא הוא דמאי שנא ארבע כוסות מקידוש דכל השנה שאחד מוציא את כולם ומיהו גם בקידוש שמא היה לכל אחד כוס כדמשמע לקמן (דף קו.) גבי חזיה לההוא סבא דגחין ושתי אבל בפרק בכל מערבין (עירובין דף מ:) גבי זמן משמע קצת שלא היה לכל אחד כוסו ועוד דאמר בגמרא (לקמן דף קח:) השקה מהן לבניו ולבני ביתו יצא והוא דשתה רובא דכסא משמע דהם יצאו בשמיעה דהא בעינן רובא דכסא ועוד דמשמע דלכתחלה אין רגילות להשקותם מיהו יש לדחות בשיש להם כוס לעצמם אי נמי בבניו ובני ביתו קטנים מיירי שלא הגיעו לחינוך ואין אשתו בכלל ומיהו בגמרא משמע שצריך כל אחד ארבע כוסות דקתני (שם) הכל חייבין בארבע כוסות אחד נשים ואחד תינוקות אמר רבי יהודה מה תועלת לתינוקות ביין משמע דלתנא קמא צריך כוס אף לתינוקות ויש לדחות דחייבין לשמוע ברכת ארבע כוסות קאמר ומשום חינוך ונראה להחמיר ולהצריך ארבע כוסות לכל אחד והמחמיר צריך ליזהר שלא יהא כוסם פגום דאמר בגמרא (לקמן ד' קה:) טעמו פגמו

While I'm not going to translate the entire Tosfos I will say simply that he is entertaining the idea that one could be yotzee the mitzvah of arba cosos through the bal habayis (like by Kiddush) even if he himself doesn't actually drink from the cos. He goes through many proofs and pushes some away however ends off that one should be "machmir" to have arba cosos for every person.

What is the sofek of Tosfos exactly? Why is it that he doesn't find it so simple that for each person to fulfill the mitzvbah of arba cosos he must drink every cos? Why does he seem to compare (all arba cosos) to that of Kiddush the whole year that one may say the kiddush, drink the wine and everyone is yotzee with him.

I had seen brought down from the Gaonim that the arba cosos of the Pesach Seder are a "chovo" and impossible to *not* drink them (See [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22172&st=&pgnum=89) brought down in Gilonei HaShas from R' Yosef Engel)

As well the Gemorah in Pesachim Daf 117b says

> ארבע כסי תיקנו רבנן דרך חירות

How is one able to fullfill the inyun of "derech cheres" without drinking the cos?

So again, what is causing Tosfos to entertain this idea, where is he getting it from, what's his savarah? I have heard that the later achronim (Chazzon Ish, Har Tzvi, HaRav Pinchus Sheinberg ZT"L) have a derech in this however it's difficult for me to understand. Any insights or earlier sources that dealt with this would help

Comment: I would check the Gra.  I know the Graniks hold that way by just about everything(including Kriat Shema).  If I'm not mistaken it comes from a Gemarra in the sixth or seventh chapter of Berakhot, but I don't remember precisely where it is.

Comment: @RabbiMichaelTzadok The difficulty I have is where Tosfos is coming from since it seems so pashut that everyone must drink the cosos -- although maybe not?

Comment: @RabbiMichaelTzadok here: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49933&st=&pgnum=189&hilite= and here: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49933&pgnum=284 (bottom left column) ...

Comment: ok so the Gra doesn't hold that way for the Arbah Cosot.  It's a really good question.  The Tosofot seems to be saying it comes from the language of the daf, but I'm not seeing it.